# How to make output generated from shortest path in QGIS more reasonable

Tags: qgis, network-analyst, shortest-path

My goal is to generate bus route stop by stop given the bus route and stops with sequence number of single direction.

I tried to achieve this by using shortest path in QGIS stop by stop.

[image: Bus route stop by stop]

However, the raw bus route is for both direction, and the some of the stops are located at the opposite side by mistakes:

[image: wrong side stops]

As a result, the shape from shortest path would go all the way back to nearest point where both direction routes meet and then to the destination stop:

[image: not so shortest path]

Since there are around a thousand routes need to be processed, it is impossible to correct them manually.
Is there a way to tell the algorithm to take real shortest path?

You can find the example files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nFSdQpPd86ZIEzMuHyP-m_N3QW2DtsPu)

[image]